# Can't connect to pokadot-js UI from my VPS blockchain

Tags: rpc, wss, https

I ran a Polkadot node from my VPS:

```
./target/release/polkadot \
--alice \
--validator \
--base-path /tmp/relay/alice \
--chain rococo-custom-2-raw.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9944
```

But it's not working in the polkadot-js UI when using this address:

```
wss://mydomain.com:9944
```

I use `wss` because for `https` the browser(chrome) just said:

"Waiting to make a connection to the remote endpoint and finishing API initialization."

Answer (score 6):

Turning a non-secure endpoint into a secure endpoint cannot be done simply by adding `wss://` in-front. The `wss://` assumes that there is a secure connection with a certificate. In this case if you check the node logs, you can see that it rejects the connection since it cannot parse it.

Due to browser security the `https://polkadot.js.org/apps/` cannot connect to a non-secure WSS endpoint, unless it is localhost. There is a guide to setup an [nginx proxy](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-wss) that allows you to setup a secure connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can run up polkadot-js locally if that's easier for you?

```sh
git clone https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps
yarn
yarn run start
```

Comment: Thank you. This app is extremely useful.